# How to Push Array values into another Array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working with PHP 5.6 and I want to push values from an array in the end of another array so I tried the `array_push` function but It pushed the whole array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
        )

    [1] => Array
       (
           [0] => d
           [1] => e
           [2] => f
       )
)
```

What I'm looking for is this :

```
 Array
 (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
            [1] => b
            [2] => c
            [3] => d
            [4] => e
            [5] => f
       )
```

Is there any simpler way than looping over the array and adding values one by one :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$r = array
(
    array("a","b","c"),
    array("d","e","f")
);
$r1[] = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $r);
print_r($r1);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) function, which appends together multiple arrays:

```
<?php
$array1 = array('a','b','c');
$array2 = array('d','e','f');
$array1 = array_merge($array1, $array2);
var_dump($array1); // array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f')
```